# Is any element base or acid?

Tags: acid-base

I have seen classification of Mg+2 or any other cation or anion for that matter as an acid or a base, but I have never seen an element labelled as an acid or a base. Isn't there a possibility of Mg+2 being the conjugate acid of Mg a base? If not,why so?

Comment: Actually, most elements are neither.

Comment: An acid is a donor of proton. So no element or no ion of any element can donate a proton. They cannot give what they don't have. A base in an acceptor of protons. Here it is more feasible, Any atom or atomic ion can in principle accept a proton, provided there is a strong enough donor to give it a proton.

Comment: @Maurice That's only Bronsted definition and even here there is one - hydrogen.

Comment: @Mithoron Can you guide better,please?

Comment: Almost everything can *act* as acid or base depending on reaction and definition of acid and base. You'd be looking for [Usanovich's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid%E2%80%93base_reaction#Usanovich_definition), I guess.

Comment: Well any element cannot be called an acid but we surely call Na a base in organic reactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is: Yes and no. It depends on what acid-base theory is applied.

---

Redox reactions like $\ce{Mg -> Mg^2+ + 2 e-}$  are not usually considered acid-base reactions, but  over-generalized acid-base theories like [Usanovich acid-base theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid%E2%80%93base_reaction#Usanovich_definition) treat them as a special case of acid-base reactions.

Within this theory, $\ce{Mg}$ is relatively strong Usanovich base, $\ce{Mg^2+}$ is very weak Usanovich acid.

---

If we consider typical reactions by classical Broensted-Lawry theory:

$\ce{H2SO4 + H2O -> HSO4- + H3O+},$
or $\ce{NH3 + H3O+ -> NH4+ +H2O}$,

or by another classic - Lewis theory:

$\ce{NH3 + BF3 -> H3N-BF3}$,

then atoms involved in acid-base interactions have the same oxidation number before and after the reaction.

$\ce{Mg^2+(aq)}$ is the conjugate acid to the conjugate base $\ce{MgOH+ (aq)}$.

$$\ce{[Mg(H2O)6]^2+ + H2O <=> [Mg(H2O)5(OH)]+ + H3O+}$$

$\ce{MgOH+ (aq)}$ is is then the conjugate acid to $\ce{Mg(OH)2 (aq)}$.

$$\ce{[Mg(H2O)5(OH)]+ + H2O <=> [Mg(H2O)4(OH)2] + H3O+}$$

$\ce{\pu{Mg}}$ has in all 3 species the oxidation number +2.

Comment: What acid-base reaction you consider redox reaction ?

Comment: In Usanovich's theory, all of them, see comment under q.^

Comment: Usanovich theory is rather a rare animal and is not widely used or even known.

Comment: Well, yeah, but it's the answer to OP's last question.

Comment: @Mithoron But it should be the other way . Redox reactions are not usually considered acid-base reactions. As in the Usanovich theory Redox reactions are special cases of acid-base reactions, not the opposite.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121163/discussion-between-poutnik-and-mithoron).